# Why does Ivan tell his daughter to "act her age"?

Tags: plot-explanation, author-author

At around the 10 minute mark in *Author! Author!* there's a dinning scene. When one of Ivan's daughter said "My cheese, I love my cheesie" And Ivan told her to act her age (she's 11). What does that mean?

Comment: Non-sequitor: IIRC, only one of the kids was Trevalian's own blood, all of the rest had other fathers and Gloria as the mother. They all preferred Trevalian over either Gloria or their own fathers.

Answer (score 1):

She's saying something that's very childish, that someone much younger (say five or six years old) might say.

She's being told to act her age, i.e. 
act like a twelve years old, not someone of a much younger age.

Note: You've asked a few questions of this type recently. I'd strongly suggest checking out the Stack site for [English Language Learners](http://english.stackexchange.com), where these types of questions are probably better suited.